# Creating a website CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Im building a webshop, and asked a wholesale for a datafeed import for all my products.
They did not have it so im wondering if i could create my own.
Ive got all the information except discriptions.
Made a little demo version of the files they send me, and will upload screenshots of it.

[excel information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNZIm.png)
[onedrive pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fflIr.png)

Is this possible to create my own?

Comment: Yes, just use in excel `save as` and select file type as `comma separated values - *.csv` :)

Comment: Is there anyway to add those pictures to it, because my feed has 9843 items

Comment: Is it possible to make this? Yes. Are you able to do it? Given by the questions you're asking, this one might be above your skill level. CSV is just a text file, so pictures can't be added. You can add references to a picture though.

Comment: I know that you can upload those pictures to an ftp and use those links in the csv file but do i need to add those links manualy to all those products?

Comment: To avoid adding links manually, you can rent artificial intelligence engine WATSON from IBM, may be it will figure out how to associate images with particular csv record